# How to display an Image in a new ViewController contain ImageView after download it from back endless database using Swift3

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, backendless

I'am using a UICollectionView to download and display Images from Backendless Database , How can I display  these Images again in a ViewController that contain ImageView when I tap on any row of My CollectionView using Swift3 .

This is My CollectionView.

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class GallaryCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var GallaryArray = [TestTable]()
    let backendless = Backendless()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        loaddatawithquery()
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return GallaryArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? GallaryCell {

            let ImgURL = URL(string : self.GallaryArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL!)
            cell.GallImag.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)

            cell.ShowImg = {
                if  let myimage = (cell.GallImag.image) {
                    // Error here How to complete the code ?
                }

            }
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = GallaryCell()
            let ImgURL = URL(string : self.GallaryArray [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL)
            cell.GallImag.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)
            cell.ShowImg = {
                if  let myimage = (cell.GallImag.image) {

                } 
            }
            return cell
        }
    }

    func loaddatawithquery() {        
        let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
        dataQuery.queryOptions.pageSize = 50

        backendless.data.of(TestTable.ofClass()).find(dataQuery,response: {( result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in

            let data = result?.getCurrentPage()

            for obj in data! as! [TestTable] {
                self.GallaryArray.append(obj)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        }, error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "انتباه", message:"يرجى الاتصال بالانترنيت", preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in })
            self.present(alert, animated: true){}
        })
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
}
```

And this is My Cell.

```
  import UIKit

  class GallaryCell: UICollectionViewCell  {

@IBOutlet weak var GallImag: UIImageView!

var ShowImg : (() ->Void)? 


    func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    self.ShowImg!()
  }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by backendless?

Comment: I'am using Backendless database to download data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have your images loading correctly in the collection view.

there is a delegate method you can use called didSelectRow...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.passingTestTable = self.GallaryArray[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue for new view controller", sender: nil)


}
```

self.passingTestTable is another property you create globally at the top of TestTable() (this is how I do it, some may choose to create the instance inside the didSelectRow

the other thing you'll need to do is create an instance of TestTable on the receiving viewController (i.e `self.receivedTestTable` )

in prepare for segue you can select the item selected and send it over to the new viewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueName" {

        if let controller = segue.destination as? PassedImageDetailViewController {

            controller.receivedTestTable = self.passingTestTable
        }

        else {
            print("Your segue identifier is incorrect")
        }
    }
}
```

once you've done that, the detail View Controller has access to the image data and you can display in in an image view on that screen.

Comment: There is no thing to display when I tap on any Image in My CollectionView and it print (Your segue identifier is incorrect).

Comment: is TestTable your model?

Comment: Yes it is My model.

Comment: so when you use didSelectRow, you're grabbing that particular instance from your array.  Inside it should be all the data (image in your case)...prepare for segue will send that instance over to your next view controller...as long as there is a receiving instance there that you create (i.e. recievedTestTable).  Once it has been passed over, you should be able to set your imageView on that VC to something like imageView.image = receivedTestTable.<whateverpropertynameyougaveforyourimage>